# Extract alphanumeric string using Regex

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric

It seems like this should be straightforward, but I haven't been able to find anything online to help. I am presented with a description that contains both letters and numbers. However there is one instance within the description that has both letters and numbers within the string, not just one of the other. e.g.

> (FAXAGT JVM Heartbeat on prod_faxagt_08 (ft2ua937) Port 39630 (WAS9))
>   -  : Sitescope: FAXAGT JVM Heartbeat on prod_faxagt_08 (ft2ua937) Port 39630 (WAS9) error. Status is unable to connect to server. Full path
>   is FaxAgent

I would like an regex expression that will give me:

> ft2ua937

Only once since I know it shows up twice in the description.

In simplest terms, given an expression similar to above I want an output that has BOTH letters & numbers and NO special characters. Any portion of the description that has only letters or only numbers should be disregarded.

Comment: *given an expression similar to above* - similar how? Which parts are fixed and which are variable?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use this to test your regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: Must it contain only hexadecimal characters (so 123xyz56 is not allowed)? Is the length always 8? Why must it contain *both* letters *and* numbers, because both `"12345678"` and `"abcdefa"` are valid hex numbers? Is the hex number always between brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I have been wanting to use this expression in Tableau using the regexp_extract function. For my purposes I believe I have found an expression that works.

It might be a little ugly but 
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Description],'(\w[a-z]{1,6}\d{1,8}\w{1,8}\d\w)') 
appears to be working how I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

matching any word with letters and number is a poor way to approach this.
It looks like you need to grep through some logs. Perhaps [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/solutions/solution-areas/log-management.html) would be a good option if this is something you have to tackle often.

In the meantime, I recommend you figure out the context of your log and directly find what you're looking for:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StackOverflow45827050 {
  private static final String EXAMPLE = "(FAXAGT JVM Heartbeat on prod_faxagt_08 (ft2ua937) Port 39630 (WAS9)) - : " +
                                        "Sitescope: FAXAGT JVM Heartbeat on prod_faxagt_08 (ft2ua937) Port 39630 (WAS9) error. " +
                                        "Status is unable to connect to server. Full path is FaxAgent";
  private static final Pattern JVM_HEARTBEAT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
      "\\((?<messageCode>.*) JVM Heartbeat on (?<hostName>.*) \\((?<importantCode>.*)\\) Port (?<port>\\d*).*");

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Matcher matcher = JVM_HEARTBEAT_PATTERN.matcher(EXAMPLE);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    System.out.println(matcher.group("importantCode"));
  }

}
```

yields:

```
ft2ua937
```